# Getting Selenium WebDriver to Scroll Down in Google Maps Directions Panel

Tags: selenium, webdriver, scrollbar

I am trying to get Selenium, specifically WebDriver v2.31, to interact with Google Maps.  I able to get as far as clicking the [first] Get Directions button to enter a pair of addresses and then click the Get Directions button under the two addresses.  This results in a set of driving directions.  What I cannot do is get Selenium to scroll to the bottom of the "Directions" panel so I can see the destination and the Save to My Maps link.  I don't know if the problem arises because the scroll bar is generated by the browser.

I am able to perform a search on Yahoo! and scroll to the bottom of the results webpage; I think it is because there are no other frames or panels in the webpage's architecture.  Although that being said, the browser generated the scroll bar, not the webpage.

I can build an Action with the mouse holding down and dragging the scroll bar down.  I don't like that solution because if the page is sized differently or the panel is sized differently, it will cause a lot of recalculation to perform this action.  I would prefer a solution that is similar to the single "document" window in Yahoo! or Google Code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I have been racking my brain over the internet for the last three days searching for a solution.

Thanks.

Steve

Addendum:
As noted below.  I am not trying to do anything with the map itself but rather the panel that contains the directions.  I am using Google Maps because it is similar to an application I will have to test later.  I need the ability to have [Selenium] WebDriver scroll to the bottom of the panel so I can select a "Next" link -- just like scrolling to the bottom of the Directions panel in Google Maps and seeing the Save link at the bottom.

I am not sure if I am using the correct terminology when I use the term panel.  The problem is that it appears the panel generates the scroll bar dynamically when the web page is displayed.

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("spsizer")));
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("javascript:window.scrollBy(250,750)", element);
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Unfortunately the "panel" is not contained in a frame or is a frame ... as identified by the exception returned by Selenium:

```
 Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchFrameException: Element is not a frame element: DIV
```

I believe I have determined that panel has an ID ("spsizer") using FireBug.

This also does not work:

```
element = driver.findElement(By.id("spsizer"));
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("javascript:window.scrollBy(250,750)", element);
```

This just executes without scrolling to the bottom of the Directions panel but it also doesn't throw an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to **Save** to **My Maps** link with following code given in below screen shot.

There is no need to have a recorded step to scroll down the panel, Selenium can locate and do actions on any web object in a Web page without being visible to the user.

[image]

**Details of the code:**

Line6: **Command-** waitForVisible  **Target-** //div[@id='dir_sr']/a[@id='srlink']

I have added **waitForVisible** so that Selenium will wait for 5 seconds before the link **Save to My Maps** is visible. This will give enough synchronization time for the page to load after pressing the **Get Directions** button. **//div[@id='dir_sr']/a[@id='srlink']** is the XPath locator for link **Save to My Maps**

Line7: **Command-** click  **Target-** //div[@id='dir_sr']/a[@id='srlink']

Click on link **Save to My Maps**

Line8: **Command-** click  **Target-** //button[@id='srsave']

Click on button **Save**

C#.Net WebDriver code for the same. Note that Google account User Name and Password has to be provided to save the map link.

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading;
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;

namespace SeleniumTests
{
    public class GoogleMapSavingTest
    {
          static void Main(string[] args)
          {
              IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
              driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://maps.google.com.au/");
              driver.FindElement(By.Id("d_launch")).Click();
              driver.FindElement(By.Id("d_d")).Clear();
              driver.FindElement(By.Id("d_d")).SendKeys("Franklin, ACT");
              driver.FindElement(By.Id("d_daddr")).Clear();
              driver.FindElement(By.Id("d_daddr")).SendKeys("Gungahlin, ACT");
              driver.FindElement(By.Id("d_d")).Click();
              driver.FindElement(By.Id("d_sub")).Click();
              for (int second = 0;; second++) 
              {
                    if (second >= 60) Assert.Fail("timeout");
                     try
                     {
                        if  (driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='dir_sr']/a[@id='srlink']")).Displayed) break;
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {}
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
             driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='dir_sr']/a[@id='srlink']")).Click();
                driver.FindElement(By.Id("Email")).SendKeys("UserName");
                driver.FindElement(By.Id("Passwd")).SendKeys("Password");
                driver.FindElement(By.Id("signIn")).Click();
                for (int second = 0; ; second++)
                {
                    if (second >= 60) Assert.Fail("timeout");
                    try
                    {
                        if (driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='dir_sr']/a[@id='srlink']")).Displayed) break;
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    { }
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
             driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='dir_sr']/a[@id='srlink']")).Click();
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[@id='srsave']")).Click();


          }





}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I am not using Selenium IDE.  When I tried to select the link via WebDriver, I get an exception that says the link is not visible [because I haven't scrolled to the bottom of the panel].

Comment: Try with the logic in WebDriver - C#.Net program I have updated, it works. Its not required to scroll down for the WebDriver to identify "Save to My Maps" web link.

Comment: Thanks for the code snippet.  That solved my problem (on the real application I have to test).  Here's what I ended up doing:
          `if(driver.findElement(By.className("//div[@class='gKN']/a[@class='gwt-Anchor gHN']")).isDisplayed())    driver.findElement(By.className("//div[@class='gKN']/a[@class='gwt-Anchor gHN']")).click();`

But in the long term, I still need to figure out how to scroll the dynamically generated scroll bars because I may need to only scroll partially down the panel to view something.

Comment: Good, I think it should be possible to do mouse actions using System.Windows.Forms - classes or using OpenQA.Selenium.IMouse class. I  will try out, will let you know if I get any result. Mean while, I think you should post a new question for scrolling of dynamic scroll bars.

Answer (score 0):

I know that there is a extension to Selenium that someone created on GitHub that is designed for automating map applications but I don't remember how to find it.  I saw it though while browsing GitHub a few weeks ago and it uses image recognition via javascript ( I am not referring to Sikuli) .  I think what you are looking for exists if you look hard enough for it.

I would avoid Sikuli if you are using a remote Grid, otherwise it might work for you.  Also, when iframes are involved, it's a good idea to always try JavaScriptExecutor (with a switchTo frame) before you give up on automating the frame.

Until then, you can start by looking at [WebDriverJS](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs) .  Also, [GhostDriver](https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver) might be worth looking at even if it is just to get ideas.

Comment: Thanks for the leads but I'm not looking to automate the map functionality.  I am trying to get Selenium WebDriver to acknowledge the browser generated scroll bar in the panel like the way Selenium does in a plain vanilla (no panels or frames) webpage that has too much content for its viewing window.  I chose Google Maps because of its accessibility and popularity, I could have found another site that didn't have a map but still had panels displaying information.

Comment: Oh I see. That's easy.  You need to use driver.switchTo().frame( frameId ).  The recent versions of webdriver will auto-scroll ( I believe) when you use findElement while switched to that frame.

Comment: Am I using the correct terminology in calling that area a "panel" [where the turn by turn driving directions are displayed]?  Or is that still a frame?  I am familiar with frames but only those that don't show/hide.  Can you tell me where I would find the frameId in the Google Maps page source?  I've been looking for the last two days trying different Ids.  Thanks again.

Comment: I know the Firebug HTML tab will show you where the iframe is (apparently with an id of "vp").  The word "panel" is associated with JavaFX or Swing (I think) but maybe it can also be associated with web page elements if someone decides to name a component a "panel".   Google maps is a more difficult example of an iframe and so if you can't figure it out, try writing your own HTML page with a slider inside an iframe as an example to try.